# suse openssl undefined symbol: private_CAST_set_key

Tags: openssl, suse

I want to create a ssl certificate on my suse system. When i try to this like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

I get the following error:

```
openssl: symbol lookup error: openssl: undefined symbol: private_CAST_set_key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay solved it

```
openssl genrsa -de3 -out key.pem -rand random
```

to create a key

and then

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key key.pem -out cert.pem
```

to use the key.
I solved not by my self, i find this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJCPAZKfR7k
I hope it helps